# Cryptographic Code Anonymization

Tags: anonymity, software-obfuscation, obfuscation

I've been reading a lot about techniques related to [stylometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_stylometry) whereby programmers can be de-anonymized by analyzing their source code.

Resisting deanonymization seems like a multifaceted problem. From variable renaming, space generation etc... to structural changes such as loop re-writing, function splitting, etc...

It seems very similar to the problem of obfuscation, but the goal is not to make the code unreadable as much as unattributable.

I was curious if there has been any serious research into developing techniques into resisting stylometry, and what they look like?

Comment: There is circuit privacy and this is a deep theory that you might be interested.

Comment: Not a bad question, but I doubt that anonymization will have to do much with cryptography necessarily. Obfuscation techniques are generally not considered cryptography as such.